# Best way to restart website in IIS7 to 'refresh' Castle Windsor config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, castle-windsor

I have a series of ASP.NET websites hosted in IIS7. I use Castle Windsor for dependency injection, and the configuration data is held in XML files.

I thought hey, this is cool, I can just edit the files to switch to different implementations of my interfaces. I realised that because Castle Windsor parses the XML config when the container is instantiated, I would need to restart the website somehow in order to 'reset' Castle Windsor.

This is not as straightforward as I thought. I have tried right clicking the site in IIS and choosing 'Restart', but this doesn't switch implementations. Weird, if I 'stop' the website, it no longer works, but start it again and it continues exactly as before.

I'm guessing restarting the app pool would work but since this would affect other websites too I don't want to do this.

Can anyone suggest a way to completely restart the app without affecting other websites?

Comment: And what the hell is the point of the 'Restart' option in IIS? What does it do? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm. Opening and saving web.config does the trick. Anyone know anything a little more elegant? :)

Comment: Hovering over the downvote option pops up the text 'This answer is not useful'. However, this answer describes by far the quickest and least invasive way to restart a website in IIS that I have found. So why the downvote?

Comment: I've found that bitching about my downvotes tends to make them go away. But why would you downvote without explaining? How does it help people make sense of SO threads of there are downvotes without justifications?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a FileSystemWatcher on castle config file(s) and on update event, you can call

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

that will cause Application_end on so on next coming request your webapplication/ AppDomain will restart

Answer (score 2):

You could place the website in question into a seperate App Pool and restart it (given your guess about restarting the app pool).

This way you wouldn't take down the other sites in question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't really want to have to move things around in IIS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If these settings are in a different file from `web.config` then altering their settings won't trigger an application restart.

Unless Castle Windsor can be notified in some way to refresh its settings at runtime then the only was to reload the config is to "touch" the `web.config` file.

Comment: Hmmm. You got downvoted too for a totally valid answer. I wonder if the downvoter will explain himself?

Comment: @david - yeah, c'est la vie. You could upvote to cancel out :)